# Unable to connect Filestore from Cloudrun

Tags: linux, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-filestore

I want to connect Filestore from CloudRun , I have defined it on my run.sh script that run the node app and mount
command to connect to the filestore , my node app is running on cloud run but not able to mount to the filestore , I have
attached a link to my nodejs codes , also in my script after the node command no other command runs.
I am following the official [Google doc](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/network-filesystems-filestore).

Problem on my run script:

```
node /app/index.js        //working on cloudrun

mkdir -p $MNT_DIR          //not working on cloudrun

chmod 775 $MNT_DIR          //not working on cloudrun

echo "Mounting Cloud Filestore."  //not working on cloudrun

mount --verbose -t nfs -o vers=3 -o nolock 10.67.157.122:/filestore_vol1/test/testing/ $MNT_DIR //not working

echo "Mounting completed." //not working on cloudrun
```

Note :- if I place node /app/index.js after echo "Mounting completed."  //node app doesn't starts on cloudrun

I am attaching my code URL [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Bk-DCA09SR_94R65ikqj4cP9UUaDjJT8?usp=sharing).

My Docker file:

```
FROM node:slim

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    tini \
    nfs-common \
    procps   \
    && apt-get clean

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Set fallback mount directory
ENV MNT_DIR /app2

# Copy package.json to the working directory
COPY package*.json ./

# Copy all codes to the working directory
COPY . .

# Ensure the script is executable
RUN chmod +x /app/run.sh

# Use tini to manage zombie processes and signal forwarding
ENV TINI_VERSION v0.19.0
ADD https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini /tini
RUN chmod +x /tini
ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--"]

ENV PORT=8080

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 2049

# Pass the startup script as arguments to tini
CMD ["/app/run.sh"]
```

---

---

```
# My run.sh script file

#!/bin/bash
set -eo pipefail

node /app/index.js

# Create mount directory for service.
mkdir -p $MNT_DIR
chmod 775 $MNT_DIR

echo "Mounting Cloud Filestore."
mount --verbose -t nfs -o vers=3 -o nolock 10.x.x.122:/filestore_vol1/test/testing/ $MNT_DIR
echo "Mounting completed."

# Exit immediately when one of the background processes terminate.
wait -n

#main goal is to mount cloud run with filestore and start my node app
```

Comment: can you try to put that line at the top of the file `#!/bin/bash`? Did you set up a serverless VPC connector?

Comment: i have done that already as you can see my run.sh script , also i have made a serverless vpc connector i am able to connect cloud sql but not filestore somehow

Answer (score 3):

I also spent 2 days on that. In my case, one dependency was missing in the container.  Try this line instead

```
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    tini \
    nfs-common \
    netbase \
    procps   \
    && apt-get clean
```

Netbase solved my issue. Let me know if it's also your case!

Comment: I followed your instructions and added netbase in dockerfile , after checking the logs its looks like that mount is completed but if the mount was completed I was suppose to see my data on filestore location 10.67.x.122:/filestore_vol1/test/testing/ , even after the mount is completed i am not able to see my data on filestore , can you help on this.

Comment: I did it and it worked perfectly. I used a micro VM to mount the filestore share to check the files, and I found the same on Cloud Run. Have a try, double check the path, review the files from the VM, it should work!

Comment: double checked but did not get data on filestore i am attaching some images of logs https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FtJC5VdZFXD6AQX9Fk5Ww1WSKg1ljFGC/view?usp=sharing    and output on filestore https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f7tjBLVS4U-FHa-wjd9TxxGooaS46PLw/view?usp=sharing please have a look.

Comment: command used in logs are df -h and showmount -e 10.x.x.x

Comment: Did you put the data in filestore? Are you sure that the data are there? Because the 2nd screenshot show me an empty dir. Maybe add manually files from your VM, and try to read them (at list in your startup script, a simple `cat /app2/my-file`) to check is the file are accessible.

Comment: no i am not putting data on filestore , i am creating a dummy file called hello.js on my mount directory using that start up script , and than mounting it using mount command

Comment: okay let me check using your method

Comment: thank you so much now i am able to see my data on filestore using cloudrun

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240678/discussion-between-nishit-kumar-and-guillaume-blaquiere).